# Error invoking bsh method : eval Sourced file : inline evaluation of : '' import java.security.messageDigest

Tags: import, jmeter, preprocessor, beanshell, message-digest

in jemeter

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.Random;
......
```

why?

```
Error invoking bsh method : eval  Sourced file : inline evaluation of : '' import java.security.messageDigest  .....
```

Java 8 is installed by default.

why not?

Answer (score 1):

Because Java class names are case-sensitive

```
import java.security.messageDigest
                   //^ this needs to be upper-case
```

Also:

- [Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting so I would recommend [re-considering using Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/is-beanshell-dead)
- You might also want to take a look at [__digest() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__digest) as it could be the case you don't need scripting at all

Comment: i'm korean. i can't do english.

No! import java.security.messageDigest is a typing error.

java.security.MessageDigest.

why not? why not?

There was no typo.